# c++ scandir is filling my memory up

Tags: c++, file, ram, scandir

I use a function I implemented in my class:

```
bool MyClass::getNextFile(string& s_first_file, const char* c_path_data){
    //string s_first_file = "";
    struct dirent **namelist;
    string s_file_actual = "";
    int n;
    int i=0;
    n = scandir(c_path_data, &namelist, dataFilter, alphasort);
    if (n < 0){
        //perror("scandir");
        return false;
    }else{
        while (i<n) {
            s_file_actual = namelist[i++]->d_name;
            if(i==1){
                cout << "get file " << s_file_actual << "..." << endl;
                s_first_file = s_file_actual;
            }
        }
        free(namelist[i-1]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In my c++ programm I use the following:

```
...
MyClass myc;
...
int main(){
  while(myc.getNextFile(s_first_file, c_path_data)){
    s_first_file << endl;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

What happens is that my ram memory get fuller and fuller as long as the function is called every time again.

If I put the code directly it in the main It searches the next first occouring file and don't collect that much memory.

Any hint what I am missing here?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you are freeing the contents of `namelist` but not freeing `namelist` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this;

```
 while (i<n) 
 {
       s_file_actual = namelist[i++]->d_name;
       if (i==1)
       {
          cout << "get file " << s_file_actual << "..." << endl;
          s_first_file = s_file_actual;
       }
       free(namelist[i-1]); 
 }
 free(namelist);

    return true;
```

Comment: Code dump without explanation of the problem or of the fix = -1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i<n) {
   s_file_actual = namelist[i++]->d_name;
   if (i==1) {
      cout << "get file " << s_file_actual << "..." << endl;
      s_first_file = s_file_actual;
   }
}
free(namelist[i-1]);
return true;
```

Whoops!

I'm not sure how it happened, but you put your `free` in the wrong place and forgot the other one.

Per [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html), you need to `free(namelist[i-1])` *inside the loop* … and perform a `free(namelist)` at the end.